# How to get multidimentional array slices in C#, numpy style?

Tags: python, c#, arrays, numpy, slice

I have

```
int[,,,] arr = new int[5, 6, 7, 8]; // c#
arr = np.zeros((5, 6, 7, 8)) # Python
```

A 4d array, with `5 * 6 * 7 * 8` cells.

I want to slice it in c# like in numpy

```
var mySlice = arr[2:4, 0, :2, :]; // Won't work in C#, but looking for a way to do this. return type should be int[,,] A 3d array with 2 * 1 * 2 * 8 cells.
my_slice = arr[2:4, 0, :2, :];  # easy with numpy
```

If this can be done Dynamically, that's also fine.

How to slice multidimensional arrays in C#?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly `my_slice = arr[2:4, 0, :2, :];` does? Not everyone here knows python. An example?!

Comment: @ParsaFat'hollahi https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_slicing.asp i want `2, 3` from the 1st dim, only 0 from the 2nd dim, all up to 2, non inclusive from the 3rd dim and everything from the last dim. that's a 3d box of shape (2, 2, 8)

Comment: There are ranges in c#, like python. But Just single dimension or jagged arrays support ranges. Anyway in c# instead of `[1:4]` we use `[1..4]`. Take a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes#type-support-for-indices-and-ranges).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do this in c#. Other than writing your own Multidimensional array class.

C# 8 introduces ranges and array slicing. But this uses `Span<T>` to return a slice without needing to copy any values. Multi-dimensional arrays are stored in continuous memory, so a potential multidimensional slicing operator would need to have one offset and length per dimension.